# Connecting to H2 database file with RobotFramework

Tags: file, robotframework, h2

I am trying to connect and test a `H2` database stored inside a local file with path:
`/home/me/mydb.db` with `RobotFramework`, where user is `sa` without password.

I would like to know the proper string for connection.
I've tried to use `jaydebeapi` with a downloaded `h2 driver` .jar file but without success. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer:

Connect To Database Using Custom Params    jaydebeapi    'org.h2.Driver', 'jdbc:h2:/home/me/deployments/mydb.db', ['sa', ''], '/Developments/h2-1.4.197.jar'